# Pinsker's Inequality for Metric Spaces!

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, information-theory, total-variation

Let $p$ and $q$ be two probability distributions on a countable set $X$. Then the total variation distance $V(p,q)$ between $p$ and $q$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
V(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in X}|p(x)-q(x)|
\end{equation}

Also, Pinkser's Inequality relates the total variation distance to the KL-divergence as follows:
\begin{equation*}
V(p,q)\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}D_{KL}(p\|q)}
\end{equation*}

I am trying to generalize this result to compact metric spaces i.e., Let $X$ be a compact metric spaces that can be partitioned into $K$ disjoint sets denoted by $C_k$, $k=1,2,\ldots,K$ such that
\begin{align*}
\cup_{k=1}^KC_k=X, &&\text{and}\quad  C_i\cap C_j=\emptyset \quad i\ne j
\end{align*}

Can I do it directly by defining $V(p,q)$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
V(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^K|p(C_i)-q(C_i)|
\end{equation}

and does the Pinkser inequality still hold?

Comment: $V$ is not equal to what you have written. You need a supremum over all finite partitions. Similarly for KL. Beyond that things should be straightforward, you in fact only need Pinsker's for finitely valued laws (which in turn only needs Pinsker's for binary laws).

Comment: Total Variation is equal to half the $\ell_1$ distance of the probability measure for finite countable sets. Please see Proposition 1.2 here: https://ece.iisc.ac.in/~parimal/2019/statphy/lecture-14.pdf

Comment: Sure, I'm aware. The point I'm making is that you're looking at only one finite partition in the formula you've written, but why is that partition the relevant one? Why can't I look at a different partition? If you chase the definition $V(P,Q) = \sup_{A} P(A) - Q(A),$ then your choice restricts the sets $A$ to unions of some of the members of the partition you have. In order to get at the full distance, you need to consider all possible partitions (it's in fact not obvious that such a supremum would equal $V$, one needs to argue this).

Comment: Anyway, upshot is that $V(p,q) = \sup_{\{C\}} \frac{1}{2}\sum |p(C_i) - q(C_i)|,$ where the supremum is over all finite partitions of the space. This is only a small complication as far as the proof of Pinsker's ineq. is concerned, but needs to be dealt with.

Comment: Perhaps an analogy with integration would help illustrate the point I'm trying to make. In effect $\sum |p(C_i) - q(C_i)|$ is similar to an approximation to the integral $\int |p - q|$ that you get when you pick a particular partition of the domain. But total variation in fact *is* the integral. To get to this, you need to consider all possible partitions (recall the Riemann integral). This can in fact be made exact, but the analogy is more important.

Comment: Ahan - I understand. This implies that, my definition of $V=\frac{1}{2}\sum|p(C_i)-q(C_i)|$ lower bounds the actual total variation distance? right?

Comment: Yes, certainly. (Also, a caveat to my earlier comment - the partitions need to, of course, be measurable).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Just define a distribution $p'$ on the set $Y = \{C_1, \ldots, C_K\}$ by $P(p' =C_k) = P(p \in C_k)$ for each $k \le K$. Then apply the countable set case.